# Error in passing data.java.lang.Null pointer exception while getiing the json data

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, android-listfragment

I am doing fragements in custom listview, while fetching the json data from server database to android mobile it shows an error like data.java.lang.null pointer exception. please tell me how to solve this problem i mention my code below

```
       i try this code
    public class MyListFragment1 extends ListFragment {
private static final Context Context = null;
ImageView back;
String url = Main.url;
String Qrimage;
Bitmap bmp;

AppetiserFragment adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater gridInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = gridInflater.inflate(R.layout.applistviewfragment, null);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "test.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("Log", "Error in Connection" + e.toString());

        // Intent intent = new Intent(ViewQRCode.this, PimCarder.class);

        // startActivity(intent);

    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("appetiser");
        ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new AppetiserFragment(Context, json);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log", "Error in Passing data" + e.toString());
    }
}

  }
```

AppetiserFragment.class

```
     public class AppetiserFragment extends BaseAdapter {
public static ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> itemprice = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> image = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
String url = Main.url;
public Context Context;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, price, desc, itemno;
String[] itemnames, checkeditems, itemnos;
String[] prices;
String[] descs;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public AppetiserFragment(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    System.out.println(imageArrayJson);//here i can print json data
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];(here after code not runs correctly i thought here only the problem)
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.prices = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.descs = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnos = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);

            qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
            itemname = image.getString("itemname");
            itemno = new Integer(i + 1).toString();
            price = image.getString("price");
            desc = image.getString("itemdesc");
            System.out.println(price);
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            prices[i] = price;
            descs[i] = desc;
            itemnos[i] = itemno;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public AppetiserFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appetiserlistview, null);
        System.out.println("prakash");
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.appetiserimage);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appetisertext);
        viewHolder.desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appetiserdesc);
        viewHolder.price = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.appetiserprice);
        viewHolder.appitemnum = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.appitemno);
        // viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);
    viewHolder.appitemnum.setText(itemnos[position]);
    viewHolder.price.setText(prices[position]);
    viewHolder.desc.setText(descs[position]);
    // viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(itemnames[position]);
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(itemnames[position]);

    return view;
}

public void clear() {
    arr.clear();
    itemprice.clear();
    image.clear();
}

static class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView text, price, desc, appitemnum;
    protected ImageView image;
    public static CheckBox checkbox = null;
}
```

}
please tell me how to solve the problem...please help me

Comment: Where is the error? In what line?

Comment: qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing i am seeing is you forgot to initialize your context.

Change this

```
 private static final Context Context = null;   //variable name should not be reserved keyword
```

to

```
private Context context= null;  
context= getActivity().getApplicationContext();  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<



adapter = new AppetiserFragment(Context, json);
```

Comment: adapter = new AppetiserFragment(Context, json); i called.. but instead of context if i kept this means it shows an error

Comment: Sir,i already did custom listview. in that i passed this,json as constructor to AppetiserFragment. but here in fragment list if pass this means it shows an error

Comment: I intialize at starting private static final Context Context = null;

Comment: naveen if you initialize it to null.then it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: ya sir i can print the json data. Now i am facing the problem in getview method in base adapter class.  thanks for your help

Comment: @VipulShah Thanks , I am made the same mistake(Sumit-Inbotics)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class mm {
    private static String p;

    static void ll (String h){
        p=h;    
    }

    static String get(){    
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ll("Mozambique is a nica country");

        System.out.println(get());
    }
}
```

Note:- the returning method should have no parameters.